# How to install Linux on a macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, install, unix, efi

How do I install Ubuntu from DVD?

it's a 13 inch macbook, late 2008.  Intel core duo, 2GB RAM.

Comment: ok, held down option key during boot. Seeing some errors like: https://askubuntu.com/q/133946/45156 but now got an Ubuntu splash screen. It was just odd, because I selected the "windows" option to install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Download Ubuntu Live CD and burn it.
2. Install rEFIt (this step is optional, you can hold 'Alt' to select
   partition everytime instead).
3. Use Boot Camp Assistant (it's in Applications/Utilities) to create
   new partition. I allocate 5GB partition.
4. Insert the live CD into the drive and reboot
5. Hold down ‘C’ button at the black screen to boot from CD.
6. Follow usual Ubuntu installation step. In keyboard selection screen,
   choose “macintosh”.
7. In partitioning screen, choose ‘manually edit partition table’.
8. Delete the 5GB partition just created from BootCamp. Then create the
   ext3 partition at the same size. Mount it as ‘/’.
9. Complete the installation process. Then reboot.
10. If you install rEFIt, the boot menu will show up. If not, hold
     'Alt' button for a while and select the Windows partition for
     Ubuntu.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20live%20CD

If this doesn't work, then I'll need to know the version of Ubuntu that you have on CD. Rumor is 12.10 has network issues when setting it up. If you don't have anything newer than I'd recommend 12.04.

Comment: if I've already installed Linux (Ubuntu) can I then go back and still get it to dual boot?

Comment: If you didn't instal dualboot 1st then no

Comment: thanks.  I just went with holding down the option key and clean install of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18 out of the box was perhaps too much for this machine, so now trying bodhi Linux.  Not dual booting.

Comment: Yeah it depends on your systems specs. But it you got bodhi Linux you should be fine.